# How is the emotional concept of "home" expressed in French?

Tags: traduction

I know that it is generally expressed as *chez moi* or *chez whomever*, but what I'm not sure about is whether this has any connotation.

In English, *home* is a completely common and casual word, but at the same time it has a powerful emotional connotation and is often at the heart of meaningful conversations in films and books-- everyone is looking for *home*. It's often the end of a story, something like "Richard had finally found home."

Does *chez [qqn]* have any similar such connotation? If not, how are such lines translated into French so as to retain the feeling? Or is it lost?

Comment: As-tu vu cette entrée du wiktionnaire : [chez-soi](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chez-soi) (n.m.) ?

Comment: I never knew it could be a noun!

Comment: I feel AT HOME. Je me sens CHEZ MOI. C'est la même idée. Enfin. On dit: se sentir chez soi, to feel at home. Richard peut finalement se sentir chez lui.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Certes, le français « chez-soi », et ses dérivés, n'a pas la charge émotionnelle que peut parfois avoir l'anglais *home* mais le français dispose de plusieurs noms pour exprimer ce concept et on pourra parfois préférer un autre mot que « chez-soi » selon le contexte.

**Chez-soi** (n.m.) (qui va se décliner avec le pronom approprié) est peut-être le plus neutre (avec « maison » qui ne rentre pas dans mon propos ici). Il peut être employé au sens propre :

> J'arrive de chez moi.
>
> Mettez-vous à l'aise, faites comme chez vous.

ou au sens figuré :

> « Ce privilège d'être partout chez soi n'appartient qu'aux rois, aux filles et aux voleurs. »  (*Splendeurs et Misères des courtisanes*, Honoré de Balzac)

**Foyer** (n.m.)
 Son étymologie (du latin *focarius*, feu) confère une certaine valeur affective à l'emploi de ce mot dans son sens figuré. C'est le terme que je choisirais pour exprimer ce que tu appelles *emotional connotation*.

> « C'est que la reconnaissance de Pénélope, donc l'identité d'Ulysse enfin de retour au foyer auprès de sa femme fidèle, est liée à un autre signe de reconnaissance qui fait exploser la métaphore et décrit l'« enracinement » comme un propre. (*La Nostalgie: Quand donc est-on chez soi ?*, Barbara Cassin)
>
> « Tu dormais d'une respiration céleste qui ne s'interrompit point lorsque j'ouvris la porte de la chambre. Il faisait bon d'être enfin de retour au foyer » (*Les Deux Mages de Venise*, Philippe André)

**Bercail** (n.m.)
Ce mot est plus familier que les deux précédents. Son étymologie (dérivé de brebis, c'est à l'origine l'enclos où étaient gardés moutons et brebis) lui a conféré d'abord une connotation religieuse - ou du moins communautaire, comme l'anglais *fold*, mais il peut aussi simplement vouloir dire « chez soi ». Il s'emploie presque toujours avec un verbe de mouvement indiquant un retour (conduire, ramener, retourner,..)

> « Il freina devant la grande porte, faisant gicler les gravillons. Il mit ses mains sur le volant, y appuya sa tête. Lâcha prise. Il était rentré au bercail. Son père et sa mère apparurent sur le seuil. » (*Face au destin*, Dominique Calamel)
>
> « ... j'étais décidée à ne pas te courir après, à attendre que tu nous reviennes, tête basse, après t'être frottée à un quotidien moins douillet que le nôtre. Ta mère, elle, n'avait qu'une obsession après ton appel depuis la Côte d'Azur : te ramener au bercail. » (*Au bout du chemin*, Patricia Hespel)

**Pénates** (toujours employé au pluriel)
 Les pénates, dans la mythologie latine, sont les dieux protecteurs du foyer, on peut l'employer pour parler d'un chez-soi mais c'est plutôt ironique et toujours familier.

> « C'est un soir, juste après l'orage. Son amant vient de larenvoyer pour toujours à ses pénates. C'est là qu'elle va. On  l'attend. » (*Mère agitée*,  Nathalie Azoulai)
>
> « Non qu'il me déplaise de voyager, j'ai fait des portraits de célébrités ou de gens connus qui m'ont amenée à aller en Europe, en Amérique latine, en Australie, mais au bout de deux semaines je n'ai qu'une envie, regagner mes pénates. » (*Une Seconde chance*, traduit d'après Mary Higgins Clark)

Answer (score 3):

Although it’s possibly not the kind of “home” that you’re asking about, I think that  **sometimes** “home” is used in English phrases (and song/movie titles) like “Home sweet home”/“There’s no place like home” /”Home is where the heart is”/(Sweet Home Alabama) to mean not the physical family residence, but rather the country/region/state/city of one’s birth, and in those cases I think the emotional attachment you describe can be captured well with “patrie, such as in

> [“O Patrie, {ma} belle/douce/chere,
>   Patrie”](https://books.google.com/books?id=QDVOAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=%22patrie+belle+patrie%22&source=bl&ots=PI7MZLflpx&sig=ZRnIPLEvgSi0dU6q_6ypntrHHXY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi80JeLw7fMAhWIrYMKHUe5BmIQ6AEIJjAC#v=onepage&q=%22patrie%20belle%20patrie%22&f=false)

(paraphrased from *Le Congo belge illustré*, via ‘Google Books*)

> [**patrie**](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-definition/patrie) 
>   nf
>       1 nation dont on se sent membre
>   **2 pays, ville natale**

(from ‘Reverso,’ with emphasis added to the meaning most relevant to the question/answer)

It’s perhaps interesting to note that ‘Reverso’s’ translation of [“**home**sick”](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-french/homesick) includes, as it does in English, both the missing of one’s “home” or family and the missing of a place, [including one’s country?}.

> Homesick  adj
>      to be homesick        (for a place)    avoir le mal
>   du pays
>     (missing one's family)    s'ennuyer de sa famille

Comment: Effectivement  quand *home* recoupe le sens de l'allemand *Heim* (*Ich habe Heimweh* ; *meine Heimat*) on le traduit en français pays ou patrie.

Answer (score 0):

Well, *chez moi/chez soi* can indeed have quite a strong emotinal connotation, but not as strong as home I would say.
For instance, we don't a *home sweet home* thing...
I would say we put more emphasis on the meaning than on the word when we want to express the 'little girl in Oz' feeling.

Comment: _Foyer doux foyer_ ? Je ne vois pas vraiment de différence ; on ne serait pas simplement plus habitué d'entendre ça en anglais ? Merci.

Answer (score -1):

This is where some words cannot be translated directly because there is no equivalent. My view is that German language has precise words to describe how warm and welcoming a house is (heimat, as said in other comments) because people spend time inside, have a developed board game culture, etc... (Swedish have their IKEA :-)) French used to be more outside, because the weather conditions have allowed it, thus sculpting the language and the associated culture. 
My point here is that you might need a full sentence to reflect the connotations of the "English home". 
The French patrie is kind of neutral, the German Vaterland refers to the father and the English Motherland refers to the mother... First meaning could be translated easily, but needs more to be fully understood.

Comment: "patrie" definitely refers to the father, it's from the latin "pater", which means... "father". "Foyer" means literaly "a place where there is a fire", so if that doesn't describe the warmth of a house, I don't know what does it.

Comment: @Anne Aunyme You have a very good point. When I was writing my lines, I felt that the link to the father or mother was more direct in German or English than French. I guess I do not think in Latin to feel such a connection, but you do !