# What are the different ways one can refer to the home in everyday French

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

For instance how do I say “when will you be home?” to my wife in an informal way and referring to our home?

Is there a French word for home as distinct from house and apartment, as there is in English?

Answer (score 10):

[Maison](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/french-english/maison) is not only used for the building but is also used to refer to the place where you live.

*Je suis à la maison*. → I'm at home.

We can also use *chez moi*/ *chez toi* /*chez nous* etc.

*Il est chez lui* → He's at home.

But in the case of your sentence what is really meant is "when will you be **back** home?" so we would use neither.

- *Quand vas-tu rentrer* ? /*Quand rentres-tu* ?

would probably be what most people say.

The answers [to this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/18955/358) will tell you more on how the French language can express the idea of home in other contexts. And [there](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/25663/358) a specific question on "Home sweet home".

Comment: Dans un contexte peut-être un peu plus formel, on a aussi le *domicile* avec lequel certains amateurs de musique jouaient pour, sur leur portail, écrire les notes : do, mi, si, la, do, ré.

Comment: @aCOSwt C'est trop administratif pour le contexte de la question. Je ne l’emploierais pas en parlant avec mon conjoint.

Comment: Pour moi, "chez soi" est ce qui répond le mieux à la question, étant donné que c'est indépendant du fait de vivre en maison ou en appartement. On dira "je rentre chez moi" dans tous les cas, mais un habitant d'appartement dira "je rentre à l'appart(ement)" plus fréquemment que "je rentre à la maison".

Comment: @Rafalon [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/maison) "À la maison. Chez soi. Aller, être à la maison; (aimer) rester à la maison." *Petit Robert* : « habitation, logement, qu'il s'agisse ou non d'un bâtiment entier, chez-soi, demeure, domicile, foyer, home, logis. Il aime rester à la maison : chez lui. Rentrer à la maison ». Et je ne vais pas faire tous les dictionnaires.

Comment: @Laure Je suis français et habite en appartement, les seules fois où j'utilise "je rentre à la maison", je me corrige et je rajoute "enfin, à l'appart", et c'est uniquement parce que j'ai vécu 20 ans dans une maison avant d'être en appartement. Après, je ne parle pas forcément au nom de tous les français, ni de l'académie française, simplement en mon nom ;)

Answer (score 5):

For your specific example, the most colloquial and natural way would be, to me:

> Tu rentres quand (à la maison) ?

It works if she's gone for days abroad and you don't know if she comes back soon, it works if she has left for 5 minutes and is already on her way back home.

If I'm already at home and I know she's on her way back, maybe I'd say:

> Tu arrives quand ?

If I had a wife, that is.

Note that "maison" in such a case refers to the place you live, wether it's a house, an apartment, a car, it could even be a country so yeah it's "home".

Answer (score 1):

Complément non essentiel aux autres réponses, qui traitent les possibilités principales

There is a humourous, playful way to refer to the home and it is also used to mean « home » in the sense of « home country ». That's the word "bercail" which has, among others, religious connotations. However it is a colloquial term and is not naturally  used  in a formal sentence.

- Quand tu rentres au bercail ?
- Quand  rentres-tu au bercail ? (*not likely*)

Comment: +1 pour le *bercail* qui est précisément celui auquel je pensais bien que... j'ai toujours préféré *rentrer dans mes **pénates*** qui, pour ne l'avoir jamais entendu, dans ce sens, que dans une région précise est possiblement régional. Mon passé estudiantin m'en voudrait tout autant d'oublier la ***thurne*** qui fut mon *chez-moi* le temps de... cuber!

Comment: @aCOSwt Non, pas du tout régional : B. Fam. ou plais. Maison où l'on habite. Synon. foyer, habitation, domicile. Regagner ses pénates. La thurne, je crois, est dans une certaine partie des cas au moins limitée à une seule pièce (chambre) :  Chambre d'internat, généralement occupée par deux élèves; pièce réservée à l'étude ; cependant, la seule orthographe du TLFi est « *turne* ».

Comment: 1- [Already mentioned](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/18960/358) in an answer on how to convey the general idea of *home* in French. And I would never use the word *bercail* in the context given in the question, unless  specifically in the case of someone having left home for a rather long time (not just to go to work during the day) and with the possible intent  to leave it for good. "When will you be home" doesn't  specifically convey this idea. 2- *Quand tu rentres (au bercail) ?* is a very unlikely phrasing in French, we would say *Tu rentres quand (à la maison) ?

Comment: Il y a d'autres sources que le TLF. Là je ne dirais pas qu'il est démodé depuis longtemps (normal il n'est pas mis à jour, mais il reste une bonne référence pour la langue du siècle dernier) parce que l'orthographe avec un h (par similarité avec le h de khâgne, dit-on) est la plus courante (la seule peut-être parmi les élèves des Grandes Ècoles) depuis les années (19)50. Ce sont ceux qui la parlent et l'écrivent qui font la langue et pas les (seuls) dictionnaires (surtout quand ils ne sont plus mis à jour, auquel cas ils ne sont plus qu'une référence historique).

Comment: @Laure J'ai aussi très souvent entendu le mot « turne » employé dans des contextes n'ayant rien à voir avec la vie des étudiants ; c'est une forme largement utilisée ; je crois qu'il ne faut pas accorder d'importance à « thurne », ça n'apporte rien à la langue, la complique inutilement. Il est vrai que « thurne » est souvent utilisé mais « turne » l'est tout autant ; (1/2)

Comment: @Laure je vais opter pour la simplicité : turne. ([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=turne%2Cthurne&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cturne%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthurne%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cturne%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthurne%3B%2Cc0))

Comment: Quand @aCOSwt écrit "Mon passé estudiantin m'en voudrait tout autant d'oublier la thurne qui fut mon chez-moi le temps de... cuber!" il est dans l'argot des classes préparatoires, pas ailleurs, et donc celui où on écrit thurne.

Comment: @Laure C'est bien ça, oui ; voilà une confirmation : « (TLFi)  Arg. scol. (notamment à l'École normale supérieure). Chambre d'internat, généralement occupée par deux élèves; pièce réservée à l'étude. » . Ça donne donc deux orthographes pour un seul mot. On peut donc choisir, comme le font de nombreux auteurs.

Comment: tu as oublié la fin de ta phrase : « nombreux auteurs **avant 1950** ». L'exemple le plus récent auquel tu renvoies étant 1926.  @aCOSwt  a écrit en conformité avec **sa génération** post 1950.  Tu donnes donc une fausse information.  Tu as bien sûr le droit d'ancrer ta façon de t'exprimer dans un passé plus ou moins lointain, mais tu ne peux pas imposer tes choix ni ne pas signaler le contexte temporel et/ou spatial à ceux qui ne le connaissent pas de nombreux non-francophones (ou même francophones non français) viennent ici.

Comment: @Laure & LPH : Allez, allez... On ne va quand même pas *bataliser* sur des afféteries de pothaches.

Comment: @Laure Non, j'ai vérifié les relevés de Google : on trouve que ces livres sont édités après l'an 2000. vérifiez la tranche « 1992-2008 ».

Comment: Et tu nous certifies que tu as vérifié le contexte de chaque phrase et que donc il s'agit de l'argot préparationnaire.

Comment: @Laure & LPH : Euh! Et si on admettait que je n'ai rien dit ?

Answer (score 0):

- Possibilities:

**Penates**

Essentially used in the expression "regagner ses pénates", which means goins back home.
It comes from the *penates*, latin gods of the hearth. http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/regagner-ses-penates.php

**Foyer**

Originally the place for the fire. Similar to "hearth" in English.
Third definition [here](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/foyer/34920):

> Lieu où habite la famille, demeure ; la famille elle-même, le milieu familial : Recevoir un étranger à son foyer. Fonder un foyer. La chaleur d'un foyer.

- More administrative are:

**Domicile**

The place where you live, your official address.

**Ménage**

A place for living and the people who live there on a regular basis. Also used as a statistical unit.

**Demeure**

The physical building where someone lives.

- Finally, there are many, many familiar terms used to talk about ones' house, including:

**Bercail**

**Turne**

**Poulailler**

**Baraque**

**Crèche**

Comment: Useless to repeat things that havealready been said] here or [there](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18955/how-is-the-emotional-concept-of-home-expressed-in-french).